# where do all iphone simulator disappear to?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, osx-lion

I used to have all the simulator from 2.0 to 3.x then when I upgrade the Xcode to get the iphone 4 sdk, all the simulators disappeared except for iphone ipad 4 versions.

so in xcode 4 with snow leopard, I had ipad 3.2 and iphone 4.0 - 4.3, ipad 4.0 - 4.3.

now I got the new macbook air with lion, had to install the xcode 4.2 for lion, loaded up the same project, and only simulator I have is iphone 4.3 and ipad 4.3.

what is going on here?  How do I get all my simulator back? ipad 3.2 and iphone 4.0 - 4.3, ipad 4.0 - 4.3.

My project is same as before and set to ios 3.0 target.

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: prepare to have your question modified to be less interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the old simulators are uninstalled, but you can go to xCode > Preferences ... > Downloads (tab) and select the simulators that you want download.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest by re-installing XCode 4.2 or running a Software Update.

Xcode 4.2 includes:

- iPhone 4.0 Simulator
- iPhone 4.1 Simulator
- iPhone 4.1 Simulator
- iPhone 4.2 Simulator
- iPad 4.2 Simulator
- iPhone 4.3 Simulator
- iPad 4.3 Simulator
- iPhone 5.0 Simulator
- iPad 5.0 Simulator

Comment: Are you sure it has that many simulators?? I can't see them in xCode>Preferences...>Downloads(tab)

Comment: It used to. I'm not sure if they started removing simulators, but there's no reason they would.

Comment: Can you verify this in your XCode? And are you sure you are addressing simulators but not the debugging tools? Because they exist together in the same download menu. you might be confusing them.